# How do i show just a single related post immediately after the second paragraph of each post

Tags: php, html, wordpress

The code here [SHOWS AFTER SECOND PARAGRAPH](https://laoudit.com/paragraph%20file.txt)  works in my function.php, but i want to show only one related post instead.

it's two different functions but i want merge it together with code below.

Here is the post tag query code, its working fine but I want to display it immediately after the second paragraph of each post on my site.

```php
<?php 
$orig_post = $post;
global $post;
$tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);

if ($tags) {
    $tag_ids = [];
    foreach ($tags as $individual_tag) {
        $tag_ids[] = $individual_tag->term_id;
    }
    $args = [
        'tag__in' => $tag_ids,
        'post__not_in' => [$post->ID],
        'posts_per_page' => 1, // Number of related posts that will be shown.
        'caller_get_posts' => 1,
    ];
    $my_query = new wp_query($args);
    if ($my_query->have_posts()) {
        while ($my_query->have_posts()) {
            $my_query->the_post(); ?>

            Related: <a href="<? the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

        <? }
    }
}

$post = $orig_post;
wp_reset_query();

?>
```

Comment: Where's the second paragraph? I don't see any paragraphs at all.

Comment: @jrswgtr  thanks for your response. The code here --> https://laoudit.com/paragraph%20file.txt works in my function.php, but i want to show related post instead immediately after the 2nd paragraph